# WebView2 (2020/06) -> Where's the DOM?

Tags: webview2

I moved a sort of working Excel VBA app that automated IE as part of a web-scraping and order placing system I wrote for my wife who was spending hours tortured by the 90's style Usborne Children Books Consultant Portal to a C#/Windows Forms/WebView2 project.

Currently, it appears the basics are not there.

For example...

```
    1- if(browser.navigationComplete == true){

    That simple check isn't available. 
    How is one supposed to flow sequences of user actions without this?

    2- htmlagilitypack like tools?

    In VBA you can easily work with the DOM since there's types for pretty much everything. Where's that in WebView2?
```

Maybe I got it wrong, but it appears the webview2 is simply a browser with none of the automation tooling VBA has had for over twenty years. Please tell me I do not have to crawl back to my medieval Excel VBA dungeon. I have seen the light and it is good!

Any architectural or actual tested working code would be greatly appreciated :)

thank you kindly from Vancouver,

Antoine

Answer (score 5):

For those interested I've just released [WebView2.DevTools.Dom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebView2.DevTools.Dom/) to [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/amaitland). It's free for anyone to use.

Unlike some of the other packages currently available it's [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol) based framework for JavaScript execution, DOM access/manipulation and automation. Requires `.Net 4.6.2 or .Net Core 3.1 or greater`

- Direct connection to browser via [Microsoft.Web.WebView2.DevToolsProtocolExtension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2.DevToolsProtocolExtension/) (doesn't open a remote debugging port).
- QuerySelector and QuerySelectorAll support
- Can be used for automation, supports emulating keyboard and mouse events (like puppeteer)
- Fully asynchronous
- Supports multiple frames
- Approximately 280 `xUnit` tests
- Supports returning of complex types from `JavaScript`

More details and examples in the [Readme](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/WebView2.DevTools.Dom#webview2-devtools-dom)

```cs
 await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
 
 // Create one instance per CoreWebView2
 // Reuse devToolsContext if possible, dispose (via DisposeAsync) before creating new instance
 // Make sure to call DisposeAsync when finished or await using as per this example
// Add using WebView2.DevTools.Dom; to access the CreateDevToolsContextAsync extension method
 await using var devToolsContext = await webView2Browser.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

// Get element by Id
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
var element = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlElement>("#myElementId");

//Strongly typed element types
//Only a subset of element types have been added so far, use HtmlElement as a generic type for all others
var htmlDivElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlDivElement>("#myDivElementId");
var htmlSpanElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlSpanElement>("#mySpanElementId");
var htmlSelectElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlSelectElement>("#mySelectElementId");
var htmlInputElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlInputElement>("#myInputElementId");
var htmlFormElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlFormElement>("#myFormElementId");
var htmlAnchorElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlAnchorElement>("#myAnchorElementId");
var htmlImageElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlImageElement>("#myImageElementId");
var htmlTextAreaElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlImageElement>("#myTextAreaElementId");
var htmlButtonElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlButtonElement>("#myButtonElementId");
var htmlParagraphElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlParagraphElement>("#myParagraphElementId");
var htmlTableElement = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlTableElement>("#myTableElementId");

// Get a custom attribute value
var customAttribute = await element.GetAttributeAsync<string>("data-customAttribute");

//Set innerText property for the element
await element.SetInnerTextAsync("Welcome!");

//Get innerText property for the element
var innerText = await element.GetInnerTextAsync();
//Can also be acessed via calling GetPropertyValueAsync
//Can use this method to get any property that isn't currently mapped
innerText = await element.GetInnerTextAsync();

//Get all child elements
var childElements = await element.QuerySelectorAllAsync("div");

//Change CSS style background colour
await element.EvaluateFunctionAsync("e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'");

//Type text in an input field
await element.TypeAsync("Welcome to my Website!");

//Scroll Element into View (if needed)
//Can optional specify a Rect to be scrolled into view, relative to the node's border box,
//in CSS pixels. When omitted, center of the node will be used
await element.ScrollIntoViewIfNeededAsync();

//Click The element
await element.ClickAsync();

// Simple way of chaining method calls together when you don't need a handle to the HtmlElement
var htmlButtonElementInnerText = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlButtonElement>("#myButtonElementId")
    .AndThen(x => x.GetInnerTextAsync());

//Event Handler
//Expose a function to javascript, functions persist across navigations
//So only need to do this once
await devToolsContext.ExposeFunctionAsync("jsAlertButtonClick", () =>
{
    _ = devToolsContext.EvaluateExpressionAsync("window.alert('Hello! You invoked window.alert()');");
});

var jsAlertButton = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAsync("#jsAlertButton");

//Write up the click event listner to call our exposed function
_ = jsAlertButton.AddEventListenerAsync("click", "jsAlertButtonClick");

//Get a collection of HtmlElements
var divElements = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");

foreach (var div in divElements)
{
    // Get a reference to the CSSStyleDeclaration
    var style = await div.GetStyleAsync();

    //Set the border to 1px solid red
    await style.SetPropertyAsync("border", "1px solid red", important: true);

    await div.SetAttributeAsync("data-customAttribute", "123");
    await div.SetInnerTextAsync("Updated Div innerText");
}

//Using standard array
var tableRows = await htmlTableElement.GetRowsAsync().ToArrayAsync();

foreach(var row in tableRows)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync().ToArrayAsync();
    foreach(var cell in cells)
    {
        var newDiv = await devToolsContext.CreateHtmlElementAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        await newDiv.SetInnerTextAsync("New Div Added!");
        await cell.AppendChildAsync(newDiv);
    }
}

//Get a reference to the HtmlCollection and use async enumerable
//Requires Net Core 3.1 or higher
var tableRowsHtmlCollection = await htmlTableElement.GetRowsAsync();

await foreach (var row in tableRowsHtmlCollection)
{
    var cells = await row.GetCellsAsync();
    await foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        var newDiv = await devToolsContext.CreateHtmlElementAsync<HtmlDivElement>("div");
        await newDiv.SetInnerTextAsync("New Div Added!");
        await cell.AppendChildAsync(newDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Version 3.0 now includes a large number of `DOM` classes, example has been updated to reflect the improvements.

Comment: Tremendous work, congratulations!

Answer (score 3):

**1. browser.navigationComplete**: You should be able to use the [WebView2.NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winforms/0-9-515/microsoft-web-webview2-winforms-webview2#navigationcompleted) event.

**2. htmlagilitypack**: While WebView2 doesn't provide direct DOM access, you could get the [html as a string](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/208) and use the [htmlagilitypack LoadHtml](https://html-agility-pack.net/from-string) function. There's also the [htmlagilitypack from web](https://html-agility-pack.net/from-web) functionality, but I'm not sure if that's just using a WebBrowser under the covers.